# Colon Expected in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I have a really simple test set up in a file named test1.py but it seems to give me a colon expected error, or alternatively when I run it it says invalid syntax.
    class test1:

```
    def counter(self):
        while loopcount < 1000:
            loopcount = loopcount + 1
        if loopcount 1000:
            print(loopcount)
```

Comment: What is `if loopcount 1000:` supposed to do?

Comment: `if loopcount == 1000:`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this code with some adjustments on `loopcount` and `if` statement and `test1` class definition

```
class Test1(object):

    def counter(self, loopcount):
        while loopcount < 1000:
            loopcount = loopcount + 1
        if loopcount == 1000:
            print(loopcount)

my = Test1()
my.counter(100)
```